# Редактирование ячейки таблицы по двойному щелчку

Tags: javascript, html, table

Как сделать так, чтобы содержимое ячейки можно было редактировать только при двойном щелчке без jQuery? Сделал нечто подобное:

```
function setEditable(cell) {

    if (cell.getAttribute("contenteditable") == undefined) {
        cell.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
    } else {
        cell.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
    }

}
```

Функция вызывается при событии ondblclick

При двойном щелчке действительно ячейка получает статус возможности редактирования, однако, надо нажать третий раз, чтобы выбрать эту ячейку в фокус (ну, нажать на нее, чтобы палка мигающая появилась :) ). Кроме того, если убрать ячейку из фокуса (перейти к другой, щелкнуть по пустому месту и так далее), то свойство contenteditable остается true.

Мне нужно, чтобы при двойном щелчке ячейка выбиралась в фокус на втором клике и сразу можно было редактировать. А по завершении работы фокус пропадал, пока снова не кликнут по ячейке два раза. Как это сделать?

Comment: focusEvent в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильнее было бы не через contenteditable делать, а заменять содержимое на input.

```
cell.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
  // создаём поле
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = cell.textContent;

  // очищаем ячейку
  while (cell.firstChild) {
    cell.removeChild(cell.firstChild);
  }

  // вставляем поле и даём ему фокус
  cell.appendChild(input);
  input.focus();

  // вешаем обработчик потери фокуса
  input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
     // удаляем поле
     cell.removeChild(input);

     // добавляем текст в ячейку
     cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  });
});
```

Ну или если нужен многострочный текст, то использовать:

```
const input = document.createElement('textarea');
```

и для ячейки дать стиль:

```css
white-spacing: pre;
```

Comment: А каким критерием определяем правильность?) Переключение одного атрибута вроде компактнее будет...

Comment: Вы сначала удалили инпут, а потом читаете значение? Это точно правильно?)

Comment: @optimus-prime contenteditable позволит нам вставлять любой HTML-код прям в ячейку, что повлечёт за собой ряд проблем.

Comment: @oliver-patterson то что мы input удалили из DOM ещё не значит, что его не существует, он у нас по прежнему хранится в переменной и мы им можем управлять, да хоть заново вставить в DOM :)

Comment: @RuslanMart, ладно, звучит довольно логично, а почему мы его не удаляем?

Comment: @oliver-patterson с DOM удаляем, а с переменной нет смысла чистить, это сделает "сборщик мусора"

Comment: @RuslanMart, не знаю как он работает, но не лучше было бы самому подчищать?) Так  сказать, чтобы наверняка. Просто интересно, не хочу не чему учить и тему подобное, с таким подходом не сталкивался.

Comment: Да, ваш способ - то, что надо. Однако я до сих пор не могу понять, почему не получается сначала поставить cell.textContent = input.value, а потом удалить input? У меня в таком случае пустая ячейка. А если сначала удаляю, а потом беру значение - все работает